# Binding a control value to selected datagrid value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

in WPF XAML
i am trying to bind a control value to a Data Grid cell value, so whenever the selected row changes , the control text value will change

i tried to do something like

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyGrid.Row.cname}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `ElementBinding` e.g.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid" ItemsSource="..." />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=SelectedItem.cname}" />
```

You can find some more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms752347.aspx#specifying_the_binding_source).